# Trying to write an automated action to execute next activity

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

[here's a picture of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zLb.png)I am trying to write an automated action in odoo 15 to create next activity that when triggered sends a reminder to a generic user that it gets from the record but it is not finding the user, i think i wrote the syntax wrong so would really appreciate some input

I tried to write the field name of the generic user and I was expecting it to send a reminder for the provided generic user

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Please share the code that you have written. For more details please see [mre]

Comment: Please add field technical name only. record.technical_name is invalid syntax. For ex: use request_owner_id only.

Answer (score 0):

without more info it should be something like

```
record.user_id.id
```

With the user_id being the user you want to send the reminder to.